# How to make JSON response like this?

Tags: python, json

For a flask based python API project, I have to return the json response like below:

```
{
    "images": 
    [
        {
            "transaction": 
            {
                "message": "match found",
                "status": "success",
                "subjectId": 79,
                "confidence": 0.56

            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In above json, `images` looks like a list and `transaction` looks like a dict which means that the response is list of dict. Now below is the code I have in order to achieve above format:

```
@app.route('/api/v1/face/recognize', methods=['POST'])
def recognize():
    """
    SOME CODE
    """

    images = []
    transaction = dict()

    transaction['status'] = 'success'
    transaction['message'] = "match found"
    transaction['subjectId'] = 79
    transaction['confidence'] = 0.56
    images.append(transaction)

    return jsonify(images), 200
```

But it is giving me below response:

```
[
    {
        "confidence": 0.56,
        "message": "match found",
        "status": "success",
        "subject_id": 79
    }
]
```

which doesnt looks like what I wanted. I am unable to understand how can I make the response format look like the above mentioned. Can anyone please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. use `images.append({'transaction': transaction})`

**Ex:**

```
@app.route('/api/v1/face/recognize', methods=['POST'])
def recognize():
    """
    SOME CODE
    """

    images = []
    transaction = dict()

    transaction['status'] = 'success'
    transaction['message'] = "match found"
    transaction['subjectId'] = 79
    transaction['confidence'] = 0.56
    images.append({'transaction': transaction})
    images = {'images': images}

    return jsonify(images), 200
```

**Output:**

```
{'images': [{'transaction': {'confidence': 0.56,
                             'message': 'match found',
                             'status': 'success',
                             'subjectId': 79}}]}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the point. But your code has not included `images` in the response.